# Examples of vector spaces defined on fields other than field of numbers: $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C$ etc.?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I'm using the textbook "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler. The author mentions that *vector spaces* can be generally defined over any field. But the only examples that can I spot in the textbook are of vector fields defined over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Could someone please give me some common examples of *vector spaces* which are **not** defined on field of numbers: $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C$ etc.? I tried searching on the net, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: 1) $\Bbb N$  and $\Bbb Z$ are not fields 2) You can look at $\Bbb F_p$-vector spaces, $\Bbb Q_p$-vector spaces 3) If $R$ is any ring, you can look at left $R$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a vector space over a field other than the rationals, the reals or the complex numbers you have to start with such a field.

For example, the set  $\{0,1\}$ with arithmetic modulo $2$ is a field. Then the set of $n$-tuples ("vectors") with coefficients in that field is a vector space over that field.

For example, the set of eight vectors $(a,b,c)$ where each of the entries is either $0$ or $1$ is a three dimensional vector space over that two element field. (Just remember that you do arithmetic modulo $2$, so $(1,1,0) + (1,0,1) = (0,1,1)$.)

There are many other fields, some finite, some not. With any of them you can form vector spaces of any finite dimension in just this way. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics) .
(The integers and the natural numbers aren't fields.)

Comment: Could you give an example of n-tuple with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ ? I'm not sure what you meant by n-tuple there. Do you mean something like $(1,0,1,1,..)$ ?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for that example. So I can see that the vector space of $(a,b,c)$ is closed. But one more question: How would scalar multiplication behave for it? Would $0.(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$ and $1.(a,b,c)=(a,b,c)$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With this two element field scalar multiplication is pretty boring. Less so with other fields. Play with the three element field $\{0,1,2\}$, arithmetic modulo $3$. The two dimensional vector space has $9$ elements, the three dimensional vector space has $27$.

Answer (score 3):

The set of polynomials over a field, $\Bbb F[x]$, has many properties of a field, but doesn't have multiplicative inverses. If we define a set $\Bbb W$ which has elements of $\Bbb F[x]\,mod\,h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is an irreducible non constant polynomial in $\Bbb F[x]$ (can't be split into non constant factors), then we can show this is a field. For example, $(x+1)(x^2+1)+3\ mod\ (x^2+1) = x+4$

All the addition axioms are obvious and simple to check with the addition identity being the $0$ polynomial and the inverse of $f(x)$ given by $-f(x)$.

We use the division algorithm for polynomials which states that $\forall f(x),\ g(x) \in \Bbb F[x], \exists\ a(x),\ b(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$ such that $f(x)=a(x)g(x)+b(x)$ and $deg(b(x)) < deg(g(x))$ where $g(x) \neq 0$. Using this with $g(x) = h(x)$ we see that multiplication is closed as in $\Bbb W$, $f(x)$ would be $b(x)$. Multiplication is clearly commutative, associative and has identity $1$.

Using the division algorithm it is possible to show that $\forall f(x),\ g(x) \in \Bbb F[x] \backslash \{0\},\ \exists\ a(x),\ b(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = gcd(f(x), g(x))$. We can use this to show the existence of a multiplicative inverse.

Take $f(x) \in \Bbb W$ and assume $f(x)=c$ is a constant function. Then it's inverse is given simply by $\frac 1c$. For the non trivial case assume $f(x) \neq constant$. As $f(x) \in \Bbb W$ we know that h(x) doesn't divide $f(x)$, and as $h(x)$ is irreducible it can't divide $f(x)$. This means that $gcd(f(x), h(x)) = 1$, and we use the result above to get $a(x),\ b(x)$ such that $$a(x)f(x)+b(x)h(x)=1\\a(x)f(x)=1-b(x)h(x)\\a(x)f(x)=1$$ as $b(x)h(x)=0$ in $\Bbb W$. This means that $a(x)$ is a multiplicative inverse of $f(x)$.

The distributive laws also hold and are simple to check, and so $\Bbb W$ is a field. We could find some trivial vector spaces such as $\Bbb W^n$ or if you wanted something more interesting then maybe the set $\Bbb W[y]$ which is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb W$, or the set of matrices with elements in $\Bbb W$. When checking the vector space axioms you don't use any specific properties of the field, you only need the axioms of a vector space, and so any vector space you can think of will work under any field.